# PyCharm: Как добавить файлы в проект?

Tags: pycharm

У меня есть проект в PyCharm, связанный с репозиторием на GitHub. При попытке отредактировать любой файл появляется окошко с предупреждением:

[image: Non-Project Files Protection]

Из него я понял, что файл не находится в проекте. Вопрос в том, как его туда добавить?

Я выполнил команду `git add .` , но это не помогло.

Comment: И не могло помочь, потому что это совсем о другом. Как создавался проект?

Comment: @Эникейщик клонировал Git репозиторий, а потом создал на его месте проект

Comment: Так я спрашиваю как создал. Через импорт или просто открыл папку с файлами?

Comment: @Эникейщик открыл файл (ПКМ -> Edit With PyCharm), PyCharm предложил мне создать на его месте проект. Я согласился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно пересоздать проект:

Files -> Close Project -> Get from VCS -> GitHub -> Выбираем проект -> Clone